# libq-dev fails to install

Tags: 12.04, postgresql, backtrack

When I try to install `libpq-dev` It fails to install and gives me the folowing error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libpq-dev: Depends: libpq5 (= 8.4.8-0ubuntu0.10.04) but 8.4.12-0ubuntu10.04 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I tried updating `libq5` but not luck it says it's at newest version. I'm using backtrack distro which is practically ubuntu.

Comment: This may be considered a duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/22949) or off-topic. Questions that are about BackTrack and not about Ubuntu [are off-topic](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions). You can search [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com) for more information on this. If [that question](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/22949) doesn't enable you to solve this probem, you should instead ask this someplace BackTrack is supported, like the [BackTrack forums](http://backtrack-linux.org/forums/forum.php) or [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
`sudo apt-get -f install`. 
It fixes broken dependencies.

Comment: If that doesn't work, downgrade `libpq5` by running `sudo apt-get install libpq5=8.4.8-0ubuntu0.10.04`.